# Issue with sidebar toggle jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, togglebutton

I want to add sidebar toggle option to my page. I searched on the web and found this jQuery plugin:

http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/toggle_sidebar.html
It doesn't add 'Hide' link to the sidebar.

What I put in the code after calling the js file with script tag is here:

```
<script src="{$baseUrl}/js/sidebarToggle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      $("#sidebar").toggleSidebar({animation:"queuedLeft", position:"left", full:true});
  });
</script>
```

I don't know there the problem is. It
Would you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the default values inside the js file. I had to change them to match my layout ids.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, i really cant be that helpful without the html source ...but anyways

see the source code in the browser and  search for

```
<a class="trigger"
```

if you found it then most likely  the container which your applying the plugin to it should have a css position property ..

give it a shot ,,,

Comment: Thank you But I found the problem.